# Возврат данных в AJAX-запросе

Tags: php, ajax

В ajax-запросе я обрабатываю с помощью php-скрипта текст.

```
$parsedown = new Parsedown();
            $htmlReady = $parsedown->text($_REQUEST["text"]);
            $dompdf = new Dompdf();
            $dompdf -> loadHtml($htmlReady);
            $dompdf -> render();
            $data = $dompdf -> output();
            $urlpdf = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/upload/pdfFiles/example1223.pdf";
            file_put_contents($urlpdf, $data);
```

т.е. из текста возвращаю PDF файл, но мне нужно в результате вернуть путь до этого файла, чтобы в дальнейшем реализовать скачивание. Путь - в переменной $urlpdf. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> из текста возвращаю PDF файл, но мне нужно в результате вернуть путь до этого файла, чтобы в дальнейшем реализовать скачивание. Путь - в переменной $urlpdf. Как это можно сделать?

Прописать в `php` скрипте:

```
echo json_encode(["path"=>$urlpdf]);
```

А дальше, обработать на клиентской части.

Нужно вставить результат возврата с сервера в этот линк:

```
<a href="path_to_file" download="your_file_name_with_extension">Download</a>
```

---

**UPD:**

```js
//----------------------------------------------------------------
//
var url = 'your_url';
fetch(url) // By default sends GET
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    var path = json.path; // Ваш путь к файлу
    var res = document.querySelector('.res');
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    // Путь к файлу
    a.setAttribute('href', path)
    // Название файла с расширением
    var file_name = path.slice(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, path.length)
    a.setAttribute('download', file_name)
    a.innerText = 'Download'; // Линк 
    res.appendChild(a)

  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err))

//----------------------------------------------------------------
```

```html
<!-------- HTML -------->
<div class="res"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое. В success я запускаю скрипт симуляции нажатия на виртуальную ссылку. т.е. путем js создаю <a> и добавляю атрибуты href и download. спасибо большое за решение!

Comment: Не могли бы вы добавить код с клиентской обработкой?

Comment: @ТигранАрустамов добавил, дальше допиливайте.

Comment: Благодарен Вам!